# Can Google Apps script make a phone call?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to duplicate some functionality in our (aging) phone system.  When a voicemail is left it will dial a phone number, repeatedly, until the voice mail is checked.  Newer systems can send an e-mail, or a text message, but these are single events, where the repeated phone call is on going. (Every ten minutes).  I am wondering if there is a way to duplicate this using Google apps.  We have Apps for Business.

I imagine there might be restrictions on this to prevent using Google as a telemarketer.

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation about an API for Google Chat/Voice. The only thing that occurs to me is to have an asterisk server with predefined messages, and with a web service you could trigger the calls from Google Scripts using URl fetcher functions.

Comment: This can't be done using Google Apps Scripts alone. Considering using a third-party service like Twilio together with Apps Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Per +Srik's note. Google Apps Script itself cannot make a phone call. You'll need use a 3rd party service to make the phone call. What Apps Script CAN do is call APIs such that you can automate and integrate these systems nicely.

Here is a video and some code that can help you get started with Twilio.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0wjM1Ds3lc
https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/Twilio